# How can I modfy this send.php $mail call to include the $phone paramerter

Tags: php, send

How do I get the phone number parameter, which I added, into the body of the email sent by this php script?:

```
$post = (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;

if($post)
{
    $name    = stripslashes($_POST['name']);
    $email   = trim($_POST['email']);
    $phone   = trim($_POST['phone']);
    $subject = trim($_POST['subject']);
    $message = stripslashes($_POST['message']);

    $error = '';

    // Check name
    if(!$name)
        $error .= 'Name required! ';

    // Check email
    if(!$email)
        $error .= 'E-mail required! ';

    if($email && !ValidateEmail($email))
        $error .= 'E-mail address is not valid! ';

    // Check phone
    if(!$phone)
        $error .= 'Phone number required! ';


    // Check message
    if(!$message)
        $error .= "Please enter your message!";

    if(!$error)
    {
        $mail = mail(WEBMASTER_EMAIL, $subject, $message,
             "From: ".$name." <".$email.">\r\n"
            ."Reply-To: ".$email."\r\n"
            ."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());

        if($mail)
            echo 'OK';
    }
    else
        echo '<div class="errormsg">'.$error.'</div>';
}
```

I've added $phone to the $post section, created the feild in my form, now I just need to get the contents returned in the email that is recieved. Any tips greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you wrote this code yourself, you'd already know how to add extra fields to an email message. Note that this code is susceptible to email header injection and can be subverted by spammers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly what you want, you need something like that:

```
$message = "Phone: $phone\r\n" . $message;
```

before

```
$mail = mail(WEBMASTER_EMAIL, $subject, $message,
         "From: ".$name." <".$email.">\r\n"
        ."Reply-To: ".$email."\r\n"
        ."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());
```

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. I did this and it worked as expected. However, I created a duplicate php file called send2.php and modified the action accordingly but my form seemed to continue to call the original send.php file. Any ideas why? Am sure it was a simple mistake.

Comment: May be your browser is using the old HTML page from the cache. Try to clear the browser's cache, or call the HTML page with the form appending something in query string (http://yourserver/form.html?something)